# How to display windowid of electron app window in its content on MacOS

Tags: node.js, macos, electron, core-graphics

I have a simplest electron application
https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start

Which currently displays version of [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/), [Chromium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium_(web_browser)) and [Electron](https://www.electronjs.org/).
In addition to this version details I want to display `windowid` of this electron app window so this `windowid` can be used for window capturing on MacOS.

I can find `windowid` using [Quartz Window Services](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/quartz_window_services) but I guess there would be way using electron only as electron is creating Browser window.

How can I find `windowid` in electron itself?

Answer (score 0):

```
const { desktopCapturer } = require('electron')

function getWindowId() {
  desktopCapturer.getSources({ types: ['window'] }).then(async sources => {
    for (const source of sources) {
      if (source.name === 'Hello World!') {
        return source.id.split(':')[1]
      }
    }
  })
}
```

Reference: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/desktop-capturer

Answer (score 0):

[win.getMediaSourceId()](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#wingetmediasourceid)

Returns `String` - Window id in the format of DesktopCapturerSource's id. For example "window:1324:0".

More precisely the format is `window:id:other_id` where `id` is `HWND` on Windows, `CGWindowID` (`uint64_t`) on macOS and Window (unsigned long) on Linux. `other_id` is used to identify web contents (tabs) so within the same top level window.

Example:

```js
// In the main process.
const { BrowserWindow } = require('electron')

const win = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600 })

// Load a remote URL
win.loadURL('https://github.com')

// Or load a local HTML file
win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/app/index.html`)

// Print window id
console.log('window id is', win.getMediaSourceId())
```